# Confused about Arrays in VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm working on a project for college in which I have to create a program which stored twenty questions and answers entered on a teachers form which are then displayed one after the other (after clicking the next button) on a student form.

the issue I'm having is that I can enter the questions and answers ( array 0 to 19) however when the students are answering the questions only 19 are shown with the last question not appearing.

Let me know what I can show you to help solve my issue.

```
Module Module1
    Public myQ(0 To 19) As String
    Public myA(0 To 19) As String
End Module


Public Class frmTeacher
Public myCounter As Integer


Private Sub frmTeacher_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    myCounter = (0)
End Sub


Private Sub btnTeacherNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTeacherNext.Click

    If myCounter < 19 Then

        myQ(myCounter) = txtTeacherQ.Text
        myA(myCounter) = txtTeacherA.Text
        myCounter = myCounter + 1

        txtTeacherQ.Text = ""
        txtTeacherA.Text = ""
    Else
        MsgBox("20 Questions Created, Moving on To Student Screen")
        Me.Hide()
        frmStudent1.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Public Class frmStudent1
    Dim myScore As Integer
    Dim MyCounter2 As Integer
    Public myNames As String
    Private Sub btnStudentHelp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStudentHelp.Click
        MsgBox("Questions will be shown to the left, Place your answer into the box on the right and click next")
    End Sub


    Private Sub frmStudent1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lblStudentQ.Text = myQ(0)
        HideItAll()
        txtStudentName.Visible = True
        btnStart.Visible = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub HideItAll()
        lblStudentQ.Visible = False
        txtStudentA.Visible = False
        txtStudentName.Visible = False
        btnStudentHelp.Visible = False
        btnNextStudent.Visible = False
        btnStart.Visible = False
        btnStudentNext.Visible = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStudentNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStudentNext.Click

        If MyCounter2 < 19 Then
            If txtStudentA.Text = myA(MyCounter2) Then
                myScore = myScore + 1
            End If
            MyCounter2 = MyCounter2 + 1
            lblStudentQ.Text = myQ(MyCounter2)


        Else

            MsgBox("Your score is " + Str(myScore))
            myNames = myNames + txtStudentName.Text + ":  " + Str(myScore) + vbNewLine
            HideItAll()
            btnNextStudent.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNextStudent_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNextStudent.Click
        Me.Refresh()
        HideItAll()
        txtStudentName.Visible = True
        btnStart.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
        myScore = 0
        MyCounter2 = 0
        If txtStudentName.Text = "teacher" Then
            MsgBox("The scores are as follows:  " + vbNewLine + myNames)
        End If
        HideItAll()
        lblStudentQ.Visible = True
        txtStudentA.Visible = True
        btnStudentHelp.Visible = True
        btnStudentNext.Visible = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should add the code that initializes the array and the code that show the next question/answer

Comment: edited first post :) will try and fix formatting of it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare your arrays as

```
Public myQ(0 To 19) As String
```

you have effectively created an array that could hosts 20 strings and their indexes are from 0 to 19 max. This means that your myCounter2 variable could have as maximum value 19 otherwise you go out of bound of the array. At the same time if you show only the questions and answers that have an index less that 19 you loose the last couple of question/answer

You should fix your code using this kind of conditional

```
If MyCounter2 < myQ.Length Then
 .....
```

[Array.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the number of elements that could be stored in all the dimensions of the array (20).
Using this property is better because, if you change the array size (say you want to ask 40 questions getting 40 answers) then you don't need to check every line of your code to adjust magic numbers appearing everywhere.

But, after the change, this line of the btnStudentNext_Clicks event fails when MyCounter2 value is 19

```
    ' MyCounter2 = 19 + 1
    MyCounter2 = MyCounter2 + 1

    ' this fails because at this point MyCounter2 is 20
    lblStudentQ.Text = myQ(MyCounter2)
```

A possible refactoring of your code could be

```
Private Sub btnStudentNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStudentNext.Click

    If MyCounter2 < myQ.Length Then
        If txtStudentA.Text = myA(MyCounter2) Then
            myScore = myScore + 1
        End If
        MyCounter2 = MyCounter2 + 1
    End if

    if MyCounter2 >= myQ.Length Then
       ShowResults();
    else            
        lblStudentQ.Text = myQ(MyCounter2)
        txtStudentA.Text = ""
    Endif
End Sub

Private Sub ShowResults()
    MsgBox("Your score is " + Str(myScore))
    myNames = myNames + txtStudentName.Text + ":  " + Str(myScore) + vbNewLine
    HideItAll()
    btnNextStudent.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats the line that is highlighted as outside the bounds of the array, is there a way around this?

Comment: ok its now allowing the student to have a total score of 20 which is a step forward, however the last question is not actually being displayed in the lblStudentQ its just blank.

Comment: Did you change also the Teacher part? Where you get the 20 questions and answers?

Comment: Stupidly i didn't, i now have all the questions working as they should thank you now i just have to work on the reset for the next student. Thank you for your help

Comment: I suggest to study how to substitute the Array objects with a `List(Of String)` or possibly with a class `QuestionAnswer` and an appropriate List coupled with a class for your Student. Better OOP concepts and better handling of your informations

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
If MyCounter2 < 19 Then
```

to:

```
If MyCounter2 < 20 Then
```

or:

```
If MyCounter2 <= 19 Then
```

Comment: hmm im now getting Index was outside the bounds of the array.